# Android volley posting null values to database

Tags: android, android-volley

My app is supposed to send some data to my php script and the php script will in turn push it to my online db. But the app keeps sending null values and have tried my php script using a simple HTML form and it's working perfectly and posting to database.

Am still new to using the volley library.

Here is my registration class:

```
private void registerfunc(final String name, final String email, final String phone, final String address) {`

    String url ="http://circleincoprated.com/apps/register.php";

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d("JSon data... ", response);
                    if (response.trim().equals("success")) {
                        pd.hide();
                        Toast.makeText(first_run.this, "registration Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent in = new Intent(first_run.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(in);
                    } else {
                        pd.hide();
                        Toast.makeText(first_run.this, "registration Failed" + response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    pd.hide();
                    Log.d("JSon Error... ", error.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(first_run.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            //Creating parameters
            Map<String, String> params = new Hashtable<>();
            //Adding parameters
            params.put("name", name);
            params.put("phone", phone);
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("address", address);


            //returning parameters
            return params;
        }
    };

    new MySingleton(first_run.this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
}
```

While this is my php script:

```
<?php
 extract($_POST);
 if(isset($name)){
 $resp='';
    include 'config.php';
 $sql = "INSERT INTO users (id,name,phone,email,address)
  VALUES ('','".$name."', '".$phone."', '".$email."','".$address."')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
 $resp="success";
    echo($resp);
 $sql = "INSERT INTO log (id,response) Values('','".$resp."')";
 $conn->query($sql);
 }else {
   $resp= "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
 $conn->query($sql);
 echo($resp);
}}else{
   echo "Empty data";
  }
?>
```